# Is it possible to install ros diamondback in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I wonder if it is possible to install the ros diamondback in ubuntu 12.04. I have already seen the installation page, http://wiki.ros.org/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu, but it seems that it doesn't have the setup for ubuntu 12.04. what should i do? thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201513/is-it-possible-to-install-ros-diamondback-in-ubuntu-12.04/) by [Morteza](https://answers.ros.org/users/20070/morteza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Diamondback was released before 12.04, and was not supported on 12.04.

ROS Diamondback is no longer supported. If you're doing a new installation of ROS, you should seriously consider using a newer, supported version of ROS.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0